# Error linking discount library with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, discount

i’m working on project that uses discount library.
http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/
i installed the library on my machine and included:

```
#include <mkdio.h>
```

and i have this piece of code:

```
MMIOT* document = 0;
char* result;
QString sourceMarkdown(markdown);
if (!sourceMarkdown.endsWith('\n'))
    sourceMarkdown.append('\n');
QByteArray data = sourceMarkdown.toUtf8();
document = mkd_string(data,data.length(),MKD_NOPANTS);
mkd_compile(document,MKD_NOPANTS);
mkd_document(document,&result);
QString renderedHtml = QString::fromUtf8(result);
return renderedHtml;
```

usualy i use “-lmarkdown” flag to compile it (for discount shared library). but in Qt i dont know how.
i tried

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lmarkdown
```

and

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -lmarkdown
```

but didn’t work.
Error messages:

```
undefined reference to `mkd_string(char const*, int, unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `mkd_compile(void*, unsigned int)'
```

etc...

any help?

Comment: I reported this issue for you [here](https://github.com/Orc/discount/issues/113).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the authors of the markdown library did not consider `C++` users like yourself.

Step 1: verify that libmarkdown exports the symbols you are looking for:

```
nm /path/to/libmarkdown.{a,so} | grep 'mkd_string'
```

If you see something like

```
0x123456 T mkd_string
```

my guess is correct. If you see something like this instead:

```
0x123456 T  _Z10mkd_stringPKcij
```

my guess is wrong.

Step 2: if my guess is correct, you'll need to modify the way you `#include <mkdio.h>` to this:

```
extern "C" {
#include <mkdio.h>
}
```

You may also wish to contact developers of the library and let them know that they can fix this problem pretty easily by putting equivalent code into `mkdio.h` itself.

P.S. More info on C++ name mangling [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Hi, thanks it's working now :-)  i have some problems with the library itself but it's compiled as expected